# How to set dubbo serialization on consumer side?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, kryo, apache-dubbo

For my dubbo based system, I use the API configuration as described here: https://dubbo.apache.org/en/docs/v2.7/user/configuration/api/

Now if I want to set e.g. `kryo` serialization on the provider side, I can easily do so when configuring the protocol:

```java
// Protocol
ProtocolConfig protocol = new ProtocolConfig();
protocol.setName("dubbo");
protocol.setPort(12345);
protocol.setSerialization("kryo");  // here
protocol.setThreads(200);
```

Now my question is: how can I do the same thing on the consumer side?

The `ReferenceConfig` does only provide a `.setProtocol(String)` method and has no way to set a `ProtocolConfig` in the same way possible for `ServiceConfig` which has the `.setProtocol(ProtocolConfig)` method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ReferenceConfig` offers `setParameters`. Use the `serialization` key to set the protocol. For kryo:

```java
ReferenceConfig referenceConfig = ...;

HashMap<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<>();
parameter.put("serialization", "kryo");
referenceConfig.setParameters(parameter);
```

It is necessary to set the consumer serialization type for direct connections (that is if no registry server is in use). If a registry is used, the serialization type is negotiated automatically.